# Get url string of a component

Tags: angular, angular-router

If I have a component named `person` I would like to get the full url of it:

```
router.getUrl('person'); // returns http://localhost:4200/person
```

Is there an Angular function that does this?

Comment: What if a component doesn't have a direct route? Or has more than one? I don't think the router exposes this; what's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: Is it Angular router or UI router, as `angular-ui-router` tag says?